# Using `-weak_framework` but still cannot compile

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using `-weak_framework CoreAudioKit` and my project still cannot compile for the iOS Simulator.

- Error is `ld: framework not found CoreAudioKit`
- If I compile for the actual iOS device, compilation goes fine
- When I remove this line (well, two lines) from `Other Linker Flags` the project compiles.

**How can I compile on the Simulator and still get the framework on an actual device?**

**Note**: in code I'm using this `#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`, which works but solves a separate problem.

Comment: Core Audio Kit is OS X only according to the docs. Are you saying it's also secretly on iOS?

Comment: Well, for some reason it compiles for the device and even runs there, but I must have some concepts crossed. Thanks @matt I'll check it out.

Comment: @matt I think it is now on iOS. No?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1831/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015045

Comment: Cool! I had no idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, that's not what `weak_framework` does, and it's not applicable to this context. It says in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1831/_index.html), "CoreAudioKit framework is not available when using the iOS Simulator. The project with fail at build time." If weak linking allowed you to compile with a missing framework, they would have mentioned it.

You can, however, have another build target for just the Simulator.